# "bundle install" not creating Gemfile.lock when issued from a Rails console system command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, irb

I have an odd use-case where I need to issue "bundle install" (as a system() command) from a Rails application *on* another freshly-made Rails application without a Gemfile.lock.

I'm aware that this is usually done from the command line but I need to do it within Rails.

As a point of reference, this is easily achievable with irb. It fetches the gems based on the Gemfile as expected and generates a Gemfile.lock.

For some reason, when I am in a Rails console (from another app) and I issue the same series of commands, the bundle command does not actually fetch or update the gems and does not generate the Gemfile.lock.

As tadman pointed out, I believe this is due to the environment changing between `irb` and `rails console`.  The `bundle install` command, when executed from system(), is acting on the Rails app that launched the Rails console instead of the target application.

Even when trying to match `ENV` variables in the Rails console to the ones in `irb` I still cannot figure it out (see attempts below).

Steps to test this:

1. `cd && rails new myapp --skip-bundle`
2. From another/full Rails app launch `rails console`
3. `Dir.chdir("/home/user/myapp")`
4. `system("bundle install")`
5. This will not actually fetch the gems in myapp and it will not create Gemfile.lock

With **irb** (successful):

```
1.9.3p429 :002 > Dir.chdir("/home/user/myapp")
 => 0 
1.9.3p429 :003 > system("bundle install")
Updating git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Using atomic (1.1.10) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (0.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.2.4) from git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git (at rails4) 
Using google-analytics-rails (0.0.4) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.0.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.1) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using sass (3.2.9) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
Using turbolinks (1.2.0) 
Using uglifier (2.1.1) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

With **rails console** (unsuccessful):

```
[1] pry(main)> Dir.chdir("/home/erik/facebook")
=> 0
[2] pry(main)> system("bundle install")
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Using atomic (1.1.10) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (0.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using addressable (2.3.5) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using uuidtools (2.1.4) 
Using aws-sdk (1.11.1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using browser (0.1.6) 
Using xpath (2.0.0) 
Using capybara (2.1.0) 
Using ffi (1.9.0) 
Using childprocess (0.3.9) 
Using coderay (1.0.9) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.4) 
Using gherkin (2.12.0) 
Using cucumber (1.3.2) 
Using cucumber-rails (1.3.0) 
Using curb (0.8.4) 
Using database_cleaner (1.0.1) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.1.3) 
Using dotenv (0.8.0) 
Using eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1) 
Using eco (1.0.0) 
Using ejs (1.0.0) 
Using launchy (2.3.0) 
Using email_spec (1.4.0) 
Using factory_girl (4.2.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) 
Using foreman (0.63.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.1) 
Using kgio (2.8.0) 
Using messengerjs-rails (1.3.3) 
Using method_source (0.8.1) 
Using pg (0.15.1) 
Using protected_attributes (1.0.2) 
Using slop (3.4.5) 
Using pry (0.9.12.2) 
Using pry-rails (0.3.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0.beta1) 
Using rails-backbone (0.7.2) 
Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1) 
Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1) 
Using rails_12factor (0.0.2) 
Using rails_on_heroku (0.0.2) 
Using raindrops (0.11.0) 
Using rspec-core (2.13.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.13.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.13.1) 
Using rspec (2.13.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.13.2) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using sass (3.2.9) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using websocket (1.0.7) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.33.0) 
Using shoulda-matchers (2.2.0) 
Using simplecov-html (0.7.1) 
Using simplecov (0.7.1) 
Using uglifier (2.1.1) 
Using unicorn (4.6.3) 
Using valid_email (0.0.4) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**EDIT 1:** After tadman's consideration, I've tried this which throws a strange bundle error:

```
[6] pry(main)> system({"BUNDLE_GEMFILE" => nil}, "bundle install")
git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git (at rails4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

And:

```
[6] pry(main)> system({"BUNDLE_GEMFILE" => "/home/user/myapp/Gemfile"}, "bundle install")
git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git (at rails4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you launching `irb` and then running shell commands instead of just running shell commands directly?

Comment: @tadman Since I need to eventually issue the shell command from the Rails app, I was testing it in `irb` and highlighting the difference between it and a Rails console here.

Comment: I think modifying `Gemfile.lock` within Rails, after that file has already been loaded, sounds like a really bad idea. That being said, you're probably seeing differences in your environment that are confusing `bundler`. You could change your command to  `env > env.txt` and compare the two results.

Comment: @tadman Thanks.  I am not modifying the `Gemfile.lock` of the app that I'm launching the Rails console from.  It's a different app that I'm running `bundle install` on.  After testing, the `env`s are different.

Comment: Yup, the Rails console has `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` defined which is probably overriding `bundle`'s and prohibiting from updating/generating.

Comment: @tadman I've updated with my attempt at clearing the environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved with:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { Dir.chdir("/path/to/myapp") { `bundle install` } }
```

All credit goes to irc user *indirect* on #bundler for this.

Answer (score 0):

in my case work with  Bundler.with_clean_env { Dir.chdir "/path/to/myapp" { `bundle install` } }

note that is the same but without "(" and ")"